# Excel VBA - Is there a way to have multiple ranges on one sheet that allow different doubleclick events?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a virtual scheduling board in Excel 2010. I have one area that is coded so the employee can simply right click on a cell to turn it green and double click to turn it back to red.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
End Sub
```

I want to add different ranges on the same sheet to be able to use the same function but with different colors.  Is this even possible?

Any possible help would be most appreciated, thanks,

Comment: Add more `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Is Nothing Then` lines, with different range names for `"ColorRange"`?

Comment: That works perfectly @Gserg Thank you!

Comment: This is so common that when Microsoft invented VSTO they shipped the NamedRange control so a range could handle its own events.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4z68kd7.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this way:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    dim newColor: newColor = null
    If Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Then newColor = 3
    If Intersect(Target, Range("SomeRange2")) Then newColor = 4
    If Intersect(Target, Range("SomeRange3")) Then newColor = 5
    if not isnull(newColor) then Cancel = True: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = newColor
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    dim newColor: newColor = null
    If Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Then newColor = 6
    If Intersect(Target, Range("SomeRange2")) Then newColor = 7
    If Intersect(Target, Range("SomeRange3")) Then newColor = 8
    if not isnull(newColor) then Cancel = True: Target.Interior.ColorIndex = newColor
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Double Click Events for a Worksheet

### Luis Siquot has the right approach.  But Yes you can have multiple Double Click events using WithEvents is the correct answer.

```
Private WithEvents WorksheetWatcher As Worksheet


Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Set WorksheetWatcher = Me

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
End Sub

' WorksheetWatcher


Private Sub WorksheetWatcher_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange2")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WorksheetWatcher_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("ColorRange2")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasInzina I tried your suggestion and it works perfect for ColorRange but when I click on the area defined as ColorRange2 nothing happens.  Doubleclick just opens the cell and Right click brings up the format options.  Am I missing something ?  thanks again

Comment: The reference to the WorksheetWatcher doesn't get set until the Worksheet becomes the ActiveSheet.  Activate another worksheet and then switch back.  It should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have different events by using a form control over the ranges, but that will make it hard to modify the cells and to find what range was clicked.

You can put the repeating code in a function. I can't test the code, but just to show the idea:

```
DoubleClickColors = [{1,2,3}]  ' Variant(1 To 3)
 RightClickColors = [{4,5,6}]
Dim colorAreas As Areas

Private Function check(ByVal Target As Range, colors) As Boolean ' False by default
    check = False ' optional
    if colorAreas Is Nothing Then Set colorAreas = Range("ColorRange,ColorRange2,ColorRange3").Areas ' or one named range with multiple areas

    For i = 1 to colorAreas.Count
        If Not Intersect(Target, colorAreas(i)) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = colors(i)
            check = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = check(Target, DoubleClickColors)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = check(Target, RightClickColors)
End Sub
```

Comment: may be you need to rename `Cancel` inside check function to `check`